# get list for dropdown dinamically depending of response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 radio buttons like:

```
 <input type="radio" name="editList" value="Proveedor">Proveedor
 <input type="radio" name="editList" value="Usuario">Usuario
 <input type="radio" name="editList" value="Sucursal">Sucursal
```

I want to load my dropdown depending of radio selected

**Dropdown**

```
 <select id="lstProveedor" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
 </select>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var items = "";
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")", function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
            });
            $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
        });

    });
</script>
```

As you can see I populate dropdown with one `@Url.Action` but I want to change it and `.each` data depending of radio button selected.

For example:
if proveedor radio button is selected load this part of js:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")", function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                });
                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
```

if Sucursal is selected load this part of js

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetSucursal", "Agenda")", function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Sucursal+ "</option>";
                });
                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
```

How can I achieve it?. Regards

**Update:**

As answer of Ramon I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function getJsonProveedores() {
        var items = "";
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")", function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
            });
            $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
        });

    });
    $(function getJsonUnidades() {
        var items = "";
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUnidades", "Agenda")", function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Nombre + "</option>";
            });
            $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
        });


    });
    $(function getJsonUsuarios() {
        var items = "";
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUsuario", "Agenda")", function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Nombre + "</option>";
            });
            $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
        });

        $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
                getJsonProveedores();
            }
            else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
                getJsonUnidades();
            }
            else if (this.value == 'Usuario') {
                getJsonUsuarios();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

But in Chrome console I get two errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getJsonProveedores is not defined Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: getJsonUnidades is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an html file and it is working like this:

```
function getJsonProveedores() {
    var items = "";
    console.log('teste proveedor');

};
function getJsonUnidades() {
    var items = "";
    console.log('unidades');
};
function getJsonUsuarios() {
    console.log('usuarios');
};
$(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
            getJsonProveedores();
        } else if (this.value == 'Usuario') {
            getJsonUsuarios();
        } else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
            getJsonUnidades();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I try it as your comment but I get issue, I update my question, can you check it please?

Comment: you have to implement that function, I just showed you the way let me help you a little more

Comment: I implement it and it work, just for one problem. When I select one it loads correctly, but if I select second one it runs correctly too, the problem is I still getting value of first one. How can I drop it after select second radio button?